# How to export with a clipping mask in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, svg, clipping-mask

I am trying to export an object as a svg that has a clipping mask in it in illustrator. When I look at the svg, everything inside the clipping mask disappears. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it in the future? [I am attaching a simplified example.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sirg7ys8j78tcg3/example%20clipping.ai?dl=0)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select all the objects within your clipping mask, go to edit > expand appearance > object on, fill on, re-apply your clipping mask and try exporting again. That being said, is there a reason you want this to be a SVG specifically? Is it for web use? If not, you could skip all those steps and export as an EPS.

Comment: Ha that totally worked! Yes, it is all for web use and I wanted to separately export a bunch of groups I have on a given artboard as individual svgs for animating purposes. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you elaborate on this process? I don't see an "expand appearance" command under the "edit" menu in Illustrator.

Comment: @Rip Object > Expand in Illustrator 2020